# How do you extract the data behind a raster histogram

Tags: qgis, ecw

Bit of a newbie, so this may be a daft question.

I have an .ecw picture - it is has no CRS, as it is a picture taken at ground level with an NIR camera. It was originally converted from a RAW image.

I can load it as a raster image, and generate a histogram. However, I would like to interrogate the data behind the histogram. For example, I might want to take peak height (easy), average, median, max, or min or use a calculation that looks at data spread.

All I can find suggests you use the -c flag in GRASS's *r.report* (e.g. [How to extract pixel value counts from a raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83407/how-to-extract-pixel-value-counts-from-a-raster-in-qgis)....I)'ve kept the flags the same as this example (apart from the selected image, that is!)

However, when I use it, I keep getting a 'Raster Map Not Found' error. Just trying it with a .tiff map image (which has a CRS), I get the same problem.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting your image in the tool dialogbox (not just in the layer TOC?  I ask because, unlike other Grass tools, it is not quite so obvious.

Alternatively you could use gdalinfo.  You get to this tool via Raster->Miscellaneous->Information.  Select your raster and then click the little yellow pencil to edit the gdalinfo commandline options.  It looks like you will want to add at least '-stats' or maybe '-hist' and possibly some other options.

Check the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) for this tool to see all the available options.  For some reason this tool seems awfully slow in QGIS but happily, if you should have a version of it in your /osgeo4w/bin folder (or equivalent for Linux users) and can run it from the command line.

Comment: Thank you!! I found an even shorter way around the problem. If you save the raster as a project, QGIS generates an .xml file in your working directory....lo and behold, that contains the full gdalinfo output, including counts per pixel value!

Comment: adding to this: I found that if you save the raster layer as a GTFF (geotif) it'll generate the XML. I tried to save the raster as a project on its own and nothing happened.