# How to get unique values and cell counts of a raster in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a soil layer that I have clipped to a polygon area and I want to obtain the unique cell values (eg. each soil type) and the cell count for each value.

I have a lot of experience with ArcMap (where this is a simple procedure) however I want to learn to use QGIS. I have looked online and can't find an answer. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: `gdalinfo your_raster.tif -hist´ could be a starting point if you have an 8-bit raster. Or try https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to extract pixel value counts from a raster in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83407/how-to-extract-pixel-value-counts-from-a-raster-in-qgis)

Comment: 'Thanks! Perhaps I hadn't searched hard enough. r.report is exactly what I was after.