# How to extract pixel value counts from a raster in QGIS, in different polygons?

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I have a raster with values from 1 - 12 (0 is no data) that has the extent of Sweden. These values represent factors, or categories rather then a numeric value. I would like to know how many of each factor there is in each of Swedens regions, which i have in a polygon layer. Can this be done without chopping up my raster in to 21 (or 12) peices? Zonal statistics will give me some statistics based on a polygon layer, but not the count of different values. r.stat and r.report will give me the output that i'm interested in but only across the entire raster. Is there a tool that will do both at the same time? Give me the count of each value in each region?

What i'm trying to do is exactly what is asked about [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83407/how-to-extract-pixel-value-counts-from-a-raster-in-qgis) but not for the entire raster.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

you may use the grass plugin within qgis, or go directly to grass; there's the module called [r.report](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.report.html) which takes two rasters (just convert your shapefile with v.to.rast taking care of the resolution; 
the sample syntax for reporting on your data would be:

```
r.report map=categories@PERMANENT,polygons@PERMANENT -c
```

where flag -c means pixel count; other module, r.stats gives you a more usable csv like format of r.report